# Bean property 'listpoints' is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: spring

```
    My Bean.xml has
    <bean id = "triangle" class="com.cg.collectionss.Triangle">
       <property name="listpoints">
       <list>
       <ref bean ="point"/>
       <ref bean ="point1"/></list>
        </property>

       </bean>

       <bean id="point" class="com.cg.collectionss.Point">
       <property name="x" value="hello"></property>
       <property name="y" value="world"></property>



    package com.cg.collectionss;

    import java.util.List;

    public class Triangle
    {
        private List<Point> listpoints;
         public void setListPoints(List<Point> points)
    {
        listpoints= points;
    }

         public List<Point> getListPoints()
         {
             return listpoints;
         }
    }
```

> error:Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'listpoints' of bean class [com.cg.collectionss.Triangle]: Bean property 'listpoints' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Did you mean 'listPoints'?
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:243)
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:426)
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:278)
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:266)
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:97)
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPrope................

When I change the property name in `Bean.xml` to `ListPoints` I got the expected output. Why can't I give the attribute's name `listpoints` as property's name?.

Comment: Can you explain what your problem with more context and clearer.

Comment: <bean id = "triangle" class="com.cg.collectionss.Triangle">
       <property name="listpoints">                                                                                                        what should the property name in the above tag?...............when I  give the property name as "ListPoints" I got the correct output,but when I give the property name as "listpoints" I got an error as "org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'listpoints' of bean class